# Subclipse vs Tortoise SVN

Tags: eclipse, tortoisesvn, subclipse

When I use Subclipse for eclipse to checkout the projects from SVN repository within eclipse, the checkout is quite slow. But the same checkout when I do directly from Tortoise SVN, the checkout is quite fast.

When I discussed the same thing in Subclipse support, they told me to use "SVNKit" as SVN interface in preference page. But still after choosing "SVNKit", the checkout is still slow.

Does any body know any reason for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer most Subclipse questions, and I would not have recommended SVNKit for performance.

Generally speaking more happens when you checkout in Eclipse.  Information about the resources is sent through the Eclipse resource notification framework which triggers various code to run.  If this is something like a Java project, compilation and verification of the code will happen etc.

The actual checkout itself, whether you are using Subclipse or TortoiseSVN is being done by the Subversion client API library and not by Subclipse or TortoiseSVN.  So the way checkout should be identical.  The Subversion API fires notification callbacks that we both use to populate things like the status/console output.  I would say this just take more work in Eclipse than it does in TortoiseSVN.